# How to show a fixed number of tabs at a time in Android Material Design tabs?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-design-library

I have used the Android Design Support library and implemented tabs in my android app using tablayout, fragments and viewpager. Tab sliding is working perfectly. But when I add more tabs (say 7), those tabs reduce their width and adjust themselves. How to show only 3 tabs at a time and show the next three when the user slides from 3rd to 4th tab?

Answer (score 8):

In your MainActivity

```
ViewPager mpager;

TabPageAdapter adapter = new TabPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), list);

mtabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
mpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(list.size());

mpager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In your xml TabLayout set

```
app:tabMode="scrollable"
```

Comment: If I want tab gravity as center in above case then? Like I just wants 3 tabs at the center and when user scrolls then next tab will come. Screen will only contain 3 tabs at a time aligned centrally. In my case tabs are dots

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use sliding tablayout
```

http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/04/Android-Material-Design-Sliding-TabLayout.html

Comment: yes they are good for 3-4 tabs. But I'm using 7. They are just getting lesser and lesser in width. Is there any possibility to make the tabs scroll, like as in Google Play Store?

Comment: please try this one.